# Dynamic nesting in c++?

Tags: c++, dynamic, nested

I have a list of list . All elements will be inserted at run-time. i wish to try all combinations through all list. So the simple solution comes to mind as

```
for ( l1 in L1)   
{   for ( l2 in L2)   
    { for ( l3 in L3)  
          { 
               ... // use the pair (l1,l2,l3) 
          }
    }
}
```

But i dont know the number of fors required at compile time. So how do i iterate through all pairs within c++?

Comment: Keep in mind that this is *exponential* growth. Anything over than ~single digits for list length will take so long you'll die of old age before it finishes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use recursion.

```
typedef std::list<std::list<int>> ListOfList;

void actOnHelper(ListOfList::const_iterator c, ListOfList::const_iterator end, std::list<int> v)
{
   if (c == e) {
      // do something on v
   } else {
      ListOfList::const_iterator nextc(c);
      ++nextc;
      for (std::list<int>::const_iterator i = c->begin(), e = c->end(); i != e; ++i) {
        v.push_back(*i);
        actOnHelper(nextc, end, v);
        v.pop_back();
     }
   }
}
void actOn(std::list<std::list<int>> const& l)
{
   actOnHelper(l.begin(), l.end(), std::list<int>());
}
```

Comment: Thats brilliant! Thanks a lot. I dry-ran it on sample set and got the idea. I did not understand nextc(c) on 8th line though. But i will figure it out when i code myself.

Comment: Got it. if i am not wrong nextc(c) is iterator constructor with c as argument.

Answer (score 3):

Using recursion

```
void recursion(** lists,* list,depth)
{
     if(depth == -1 ) 
     {
          use_pair(list)
     }
     else
     {
           for(i in lists[depth])
           {
                list[depth] = i;
                recursion(lists,list,depth-1);
           }
     }
}
```